# Using NsLog for the app store to log unwanted behaviors

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, app-store

In Swift there's pintln where in Obj-C, there's NsLog. Now my question is, is there a difference when I deploy my app to the app store? Say I have a case where something normal shouldn't happen. But if it happens, I'll print an info.

1. Are these infos shown within iTunes connect somewhere?
2. Is there a difference between NSLog and println when I deploy the app to the store?

Answer (score 0):

NSLog which is short for 'NeXT Step log' is mainly used while writing in Objective-c to log out your results to the console. Println() is used in Swift but you can use both at the same time. In short, These functions are just for test purposes while developing your App.

Answer (score 0):

NSLog is used to put some info to the console, hence when You use it in Xcode output view you see not only the message but a whole preamble including date and time.
Normally both println and NSLog should be gone from the code before You publish the app but some logging might still stay in place when some errors occur for future debugging or being able to figure out what the problem was at end-user's device. Users don't really know about the existence of Console.app but it does not mean You can spam it.